# How do I get started with FMJ in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, media, fmj

I am planning to build a program that deals with Streaming of audio over a network.
For this project, I choose to use FMJ. However, I can't manage to even start. I haven't imported many libraries before, and there is practically no information available for FMJ. I simply cannot get my project to use FMJ.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the library's JARs to your classpath. Drag and drop the JARs into your project and then right click on the project->properties->Java build path->Add JARs... and select the JARs from your workspace.

You will then be able to access the library's API classes/method from you own code.

Comment: If that is the case, then I am pretty confused why the zip file for the FMJ project contained such a lot of folders, source files and other things. The jar files are only a fraction of what I downloaded, but I guess I will try just using those jars.

Comment: yes, library builders will often include the source, docs and examples in one package.